# evenly spaced array of log base 10 from 10^-2 to 10^3 in python

Tags: logarithms, python

How to create an evenly spaced array of values in log scale from 10^-2 to 10^3 using python?

current code:

```
In[1]: np.logspace(0.01,1000.,endpoint = True, base = 10.0)
C:\Users\harris.c.6\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py:279: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power
  return _nx.power(base, y)

Out[1]: 
array([1.02329299e+000, 2.61793695e+020, 6.69758706e+040, 1.71347413e+061,
       4.38365871e+081, 1.12149132e+102, 2.86916221e+122, 7.34030804e+142,
       1.87790436e+163, 4.80432804e+183, 1.22911307e+204, 3.14449581e+224,
       8.04470650e+244, 2.05811381e+265, 5.26536608e+285, 1.34706253e+306,
                   inf,             inf,             inf,             inf,
                   inf,             inf,             inf,             inf,
                   inf,             inf,             inf,             inf,
                   inf,             inf,             inf,             inf,
                   inf,             inf,             inf,             inf,
                   inf,             inf,             inf,             inf,
                   inf,             inf,             inf,             inf,
                   inf,             inf,             inf,             inf,
                   inf,             inf])
```

Comment: This is programming, not math

Comment: Everything is math :) Seriously, can't you use a regular for loop or something. What you're doing now appears to increment the exponent by 20 each time (until it presumably reaches 1000), but Float can't represent numbers that large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `start` and `stop` arguments of `logspace` are the exponents of the endpoints in the specified base. So you want `np.logspace(-2, 3, endpoint=True, base=10)`. Also, `endpoint=True` and `base=10` are the default values so you don't need to specify them.